# Mysql workbench cannot convert utf8 to UTF-8

Tags: mysql, database, encoding, workbench

Hello i have a problem in my Mysql Workbench that i cannot convert utf8 dump file into UTF-8.
Iam attaching picture , which describes my problem

http://prnt.sc/eptwhh

Comment: You might be on the wrong website here. Stackoverflow is for programming questions. Also, if you do have a programming question, please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What character(s) did it choke on?